# Using Dbus api in bluez, using notify how can i check when controller is ready to send next packet so buffer won't override?

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez, gatt

Using dbus api over bluez with test example-gatt-server (gatt over classic)
When I checked data integrity I saw that there was a problem and no data integrity. I'm looking for a way to know when the controller is ready to send the next packet?

I was looking in dbus api but did not find a way to check when controller is ready to send next packet and when it's ready to send the next packet